# Smtp zf2 - stream_socket_client() - Debian Wheezy

Tags: zend, smtp, gmail

Bom dia pessoas.

Estou tendo um problema já há alguns dias e já tentei de tudo.
Estou usando Zend 2 e tentando enviar um e-mail através de uma conta que tenho no gmail. Deveria ser algo extremamente simples, porém o e-mail não é enviado de jeito nenhum. Como o Zend suprime o erro usando um @, para vê-lo eu tive que editar a biblioteca retirando-o então o erro apresentado é o seguinte:

```
Warning: stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

Então lá fui eu atrás de fazer a tal função funcionar. Pesquisei muito e achei diversas coisas que diziam resolver o problema todas sem sucesso.

Tentei também verificar alguma coisa no php.ini e continua não funcionando.
Tentei todas as dicas [deste link](https://serverfault.com/questions/612992/nginx-and-php-cant-resolve-hostname-and-make-connection-with-fqdn) e nenhuma delas funcionou. Ou seja, já não faço mais a mínima ideia de como resolver este problema.

Outro detalhe é que rodei o mesmo projeto em outra máquina com o mesmo OS que o meu e funciona normalmente. **Uso Debian Wheezy**

/o\ Oh! E agora? Quem poderá me defender? rsrs

Desde já agradeço, muito obrigado.
=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema era porque em vez de usar o endereço **smtp.gmail.com** eu estava usando **smtp.google.com**. Simples falta de atenção.

Mas muito obrigado a quem perdeu um pouco de tempo lendo minha pergunta rsrs